# Aadhar Number Format Validation for HTML Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want aadhar number in format of xxxx-xxxx-xxxx. Text box sholud take the input in this format automatically.

While entering the input the input should automatically convert into this(xxxx-xxxx-xxxx) format.

Only numericals should be accepted.

I want mobile number in format +91(or any other country code)-9999999999(10 digit mobile number).

I have tried `/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/`, but its not working please help

Comment: Please share what you have tried with a working snippet using `<>` to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Please post some of your code attempts so people can try to help you. We will not code this for you but we will provide help with your code.

Comment: /^(?:\\d{4}\)|\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/

Answer (score 0):

> I want aadhar number in format of xxxx-xxxx-xxxx. text box sholud take
>   the input in this format automatically.

One example would be **to enforce input to only accept the adhaar number format**

```js
$('[data-type="adhaar-number"]').keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace(/\D/g, "").split(/(?:([\d]{4}))/g).filter(s => s.length > 0).join("-");
  $(this).val(value);
});

$('[data-type="adhaar-number"]').on("change, blur", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxLength");
  if (value.length != maxLength) {
    $(this).addClass("highlight-error");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight-error");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight-error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-type="adhaar-number" maxLength="19">
```

Comment: "The specified value "1245-9" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?" thanks for your time and effort Gurvinder but i'm getting this error can u please help me

Comment: @Vinay Check the updates, full string validation is triggered when user blurs out of the input box.

Answer (score -2):

I am not interested in giving u everything, but I will point you in the right direction. Use regular expressions.

This regex will help your case but you need to put in your effort on how it must be used in your situation.

```js
console.log(/\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}/.test('1000-1000-1000-1002'));
```